# Sharing same DLL with different access for different users

Tags: c#

This question was asked in an interview. I need genuine clarification. Users here can be considered as different clients.

My question is specific to C#. I need to share the same DLL with three users. The catch is that I need to give them different access. For example, say I have a class which implements S, D and M methods but I want:

1. User A to have access to all three S, D and M methods.
2. User B to have access to D method only
3. User C to have access to only M method.

While I have a hunch it can be done using interfaces, I fail to understand the core implementation. I am looking for a thorough and concrete explanation with code snippets. Please keep in mind that we need to share only one (same) DLL with all the users.

Comment: And how do you indentify which user is using your DLL?

Comment: Use CAS code access security. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/84c85b/net-code-access-security-cas/

Comment: @M.Hassan good thinking, but doesn't CAS access only have three levels? UserB/UserC are arguably on the same level with different access.  Also OP's statement `Users here can be considered as different clients` might imply they won't be on the same network.  Thinking about it though, you might be onto something if it is a web-based context.

Comment: @Steve Actually this scenario is when we need to give the same dll to three clients but with different access. Think of it as if I have built an application for three clients and shared the same dll with all but want to restrict some functionality for some clients

Comment: It is like when you create a FREE and PAID version of an application. You give something for free and advanced features only to paying customers. Usually this is done with the [pre-processor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/)

Comment: @M.Hassan CAS cannot be a solution. I will quote the blog you have mentioned : "It is important to understand that code access security is about protecting resources, such as directories, local drives, event logs, user interface and the network from malicious code. It is not primarily a tool for protecting software from users." Clearly, it cannot be used for this purpose

Comment: @Steve I believe the preprocessor directives might actually solve the problem but need to try it as well.

Comment: How can you say i downvoted you?

Comment: @Mark, @ Parrish Husband : Pre-processor directives is for source code but not for the compiled dll. This lead to  generating different version for the same dll by changing the pre-processor directive per compilation, which is against the OP needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share the same dll with other users with different access rights by using a LicenseManager class(es)

I'll provide a simple solution as POC

You provide every user a license key ( so you have a license generator in a separate system ) that control the the usage for ClientA ,ClientB, .. in the compiled dll.

The licenseKey is increpted using a ciphering algorithm.

LicenceManager class can be a singletone or static class in the same dll.

```
    //singletone  or static
    public class LicenceManager
    {
       // code for singletone
       //....
      private LicenceManager() { .... }

      public bool ClientA {get;set;}
      public bool ClientB {get;set;}
      public bool ClientC {get;set;}

      public void Activate (string licenceKey)
      {
        // decrept the key and and set ClientA,ClientB, ClientC based on the access rights
        // you should have KeyGenerator in a separate system that control the generation of the key
        // the key is delivered to user by email or internet.
        // options: licence key can be read from a file in disk or web site or licence server in LAN

      }

    }
```

The user call the method:

```
        LicenceManager.Activate (string licenceKey)
```

This method set the properties of Accces rights for ClientA,ClientB, ClientC

```
   //class  under access right protection
    public class Foo
    {
        //Control the access right for ClientA only
        public void S() 
        { 
          if (!LicenceManager.ClientA)
            throw new exception ("Not Valid key. Only ClientA licence can use this service");

            //do what actions
        }


        //Control ClientC
        public void D() 
        { 
           if (!LicenceManager.ClientC)
            throw new exception ("Not Valid key. Only ClientC licence can use this service");

            //do what actions
        }


       // and so on for other methods 
    }
```

You should take into account the hacking of software and decompilation and you should protect you dll against these hacks.

Answer (score -1):

Are you positive the question wasn't about creating different classes in the same assembly for different users? I can't see how anything would prevent a user from using a class they weren't supposed to.

Being cheeky, if conditional compilation is allowed, you could do this:

```
public class Foo
{
    #if ClientA
    public void S() { }
    #endif

    #if !ClientC
    public void D() { }
    #endIf

    #if !ClientB
    public void M() { }
    #endif
}
```

The same approach could also be done with conditional project file inclusion:

```
public class FooBase
{
    protected void S() { }
    protected void D() { }
    protected void M() { }
}
```

**Foo_ClientA.cs**

```
public class Foo : FooBase
{
    public new void S() { base.S(); }
    public new void D() { base.D(); }
    public new void M() { base.M(); }
}
```

**Foo_ClientB.cs**

```
public class Foo : FooBase
{
    public new void D() { base.D(); }
}
```

**Foo_ClientC.cs**

```
public class Foo : FooBase
{
    public new void M() { base.M(); }
}
```

**DontDoThis.csproj**

```
<Compile Include="Foo_$(Client).cs" />
```

This is absolutely terrible in practice though.  Also this doesn't truly satisfy the question of `"in the same dll"` since you would technically be creating functionally different dlls despite the same name.

Comment: I have quoted the exact question asked by the interviewer

Comment: How will it be done if it were for different classes in the same assembly?